# Programmatically creating routes from object does not work when doing it within a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, match

I am attempting to create a standard component for my application that returns a list of compatible routes with paths and children components systematically derived from an object featuring all of my application pages (eg. /log-in).

The issue is, I can place the route-returning script directly into the root react component, but when breaking that same code out into its own component and rendering in the root, it does not return any children, even though it returns the same thing.

This may have something to do with React route match, but I am not sure.

Example:

The object with all my pages:

```
...    

const views = [
  {
    path: "/auth/sign-up",
    exact: true,
    component: SignUp,
    secure: true
  },
  {
    path: "/auth/sign-in",
    exact: true,
    component: SignIn,
    secure: true
  },
]
```

The *Viewer* component meant to catch the paths and return the compatible routes:

*As an example, I am filtering based on whether the value of secure is true or not from the object above.*

```
function Viewer(props) {
  return (
    views.filter(view => view.secure === props.secure).map((view, index) => (
      <Route
        key={index}
        path={view.path}
        exact={view.exact}
        children={<view.component />}
      />
    ))
  )
}
```

My root react component, featuring the *Viewer* component (From above), which does not work:

```
export default function Root() {
  return (
    <switch>
      <Viewer secure={true} />
    </switch>
  );
}

...
```

My root react component where the routing code is placed directly inside, which does work:

```
export default function Root() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {views.filter(view => view.secure === true).map((view, index) => (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={view.path}
            exact={view.exact}
            children={<view.component />}
          />
        ))}
    </switch>
  );
}

...
```

Can you please assist me in understanding the difference between these two examples, the one using the routing code placed directly in the root element versus the root where it features the *Viewer* component which should do the same thing. Any info you can spare would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your issue is related how react-router-dom works, I mean `Switch` component is intended to render just one `Route` component at time, so the children for Switch component must be directly a `Route` or `Redirect` component instead of a wrapper for that `Routes`, if you want to do something like that with a `Viewer` component, you should move your `Switch` component inside your `Viewer` component, something like this

```
function Viewer(props) {
  const routes = views.filter(view => view.secure === props.secure).map((view, index) => (
      <Route
        key={index}
        path={view.path}
        exact={view.exact}
        children={<view.component />}
      />
    ));
  return <Switch>{routes}</Switch>;
}
```

Here you have the [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node) that tells you about that and explain how it works.

Switch component will iterate over all its children to figure out if the `Route` should be render or not related to the url path, so for that reason is mandatory that the direct children of a `Switch` component must be Route or `Redirect` components cause these contains all the props , path is one of these props, so it is used to match the current url path to be compared with the path prop of the `Route` component.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort that went into your answer, this really helped. hindsight is always 2020. I hope this will make developing my project easier than creating new routes by hand.

Comment: Not to juice your fruit, but I was curious how you would suggest conditionally wrapping the routes in <AuthCheck> or similar components. I have already put something together but was curious how you or others would suggest doing this. Any suggestions will be enlightening. Thanks.

Comment: @CaineNielsen actually you are doing great with your code, but well all depends on how you need to restrict the view, you actually could create a HOC component to validate these from a Context that contains all the secure views, but as I said all depends on how you need to restrict the views.